# Color Grading depending on number

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code where I would like some color grading. From Dark red to dark green. I tried different ways, but it stays constant Red or Green.
Values from -100 to +100.

If someone could have a look what I could do with this code it would be appriciated. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 export const percentColor = (percent) => {
 const bgColorScale = (Math.abs(percent * 100) / 10) + 0.2  
 return (percent > 0) ? `rgba(129, 199, 132,${bgColorScale}) ` : `rgba(229, 
115, 115,${bgColorScale})`
 }
 var $cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'), $negative, $i;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $cells.length; $i++) {
 const $value = $cells[$i].innerHTML.replace(',','')
 if ($cells[$i].className === 'colorchange' && !isNaN($value)) {
 $negative = (1 * $value) < 0;
 $cells[$i].style.backgroundColor = $negative ? '#b22222' : '#00804f';
 $cells[$i].style.color           = $negative ? '#ffffff' : '#ffffff';
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You define `percentColor`, but you don't appear to be calling it anywhere...

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? Color gradients - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp